# How to execute a PowerShell Command from within Azure Data Factory custom activity?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I have a custom activity in Azure Data Factory, which attempts to execute the following command:

`PowerShell.exe -Command "Write-Host 'Hello, world!'"`

However, when I debug (run) this command from within Azure Data Factory, it runs for a long time, and finally fails.

I guess it fails because perhaps it could not locate "PowerShell.exe". How can I ensure that the ADF Custom Activity has access to PowerShell.exe?

Some sites say about specifying a package (.zip file) that contains everything needed for the exe to execute. However, since PowerShell is from Microsoft, I think it would be inappropriate to ZIP the PowerShell directory, and specify it as a package to the Custom Activity.

Please suggest as to how I can execute PowerShell command from Custom Activity of an Azure Data Factory. Thanks!

Whenever I search "Execute PowerShell from Custom Activity in Azure Data Factory", the search results are talking more about which Az PowerShell command to use to trigger start an ADF pipeline.

I saw two threads in Stackoverflow.com, where the answer just specifies to use a Custom Activity, and the answer is not specific to PowerShell command call from ADF

Here is the JSON for the task:

`{
    "name": "ExecutePs1CustomActivity",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ExecutePSScriptCustomActivity",
                "type": "Custom",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "command": "PowerShell.exe -Command \"Write-Host 'Hello, world!'\"",
                    "referenceObjects": {
                        "linkedServices": [],
                        "datasets": []
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "Ps1CustomActivityAzureBatch",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}`

I see "In Progress" for 3 minutes (180 seconds), and then it shows as "Failed."

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to move all you scripting task in a powershell file and copy it to a storage account linked with your custom activity. . Once done try to call it like below:

```
powershell .\script.ps1
```

You can also provide the path of the script in json like below:

```
{
  "name": "MyCustomActivityPipeline",
  "properties": {
    "description": "Custom activity sample",
    "activities": [{
      "type": "Custom",
      "name": "MyCustomActivity",
      "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "AzureBatchLinkedService",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
      },
      "typeProperties": {
        "command": "helloworld.exe",
        "folderPath": "customactv2/helloworld",
        "resourceLinkedService": {
          "referenceName": "StorageLinkedService",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Please try it and see if it helps. Also i would suggest you to troubleshoot the pipeline steps to look for detailed error.

Also to your second point "**Some sites say about specifying a package (.zip file) that contains everything needed for the exe to execute."** This is required when you are building a custom activity using dot net then it is must copy all the Dll's and Exe's for execution.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow and share my observation. One thing I doubt is that the Corporate policy does not allow to keep a PS1 file in the Data Lake's file system. If I get through this hurdle, I will try your suggestion.Thanks!